# Is it possible to make a list from data in javascript/html/D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I wish to make a list from data i have in a JSON file. I want to select the item from the list which calls a highlight function i have.

What I want to do is load in different sizes of data in so I want the list to be able to change according to what data gets passed to it.

I have made one for the orientation :

```
function orientation()
{
    var mylist=document.getElementById("myList");
    var listChoice = mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].text;
    //-----------------------chosing which layout to use
    if(listChoice == "Force")
    {
        console.log("Force");
        backtoForce();
    }
    else if(listChoice == "Portrait")
    {
        console.log("Portrait");
        portraitLayout();       
    }
    else if(listChoice == "Landscape")
    {
        console.log("Landscape");
        landscapeLayout();
    }
}
```

I know how to get the data from the JSON file, but I am unsure how to create the list according to that data.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm following you, you want to ajax some JSON and create a list from that data?

```
var data   = json.data;
var mylist = document.getElementById("myList");

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     var listItem = document.createElement('li');

     listItem.innerHTML = data[i].text; // assign data to new element html

     myList.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

Comment: sweet. didnt think of adding elements like that. Cheers dude, ill have a go at it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Or using D3, given a list element ol or ul called myList:

```
var json = ["A","B","C"];

d3.select("#myList")
    .selectAll("li")
    .data(json)
  .enter().append("li")
    .text(function(d){return d;});
```